# Why the laravel authentication view is not working, although i am able to use the login and register functionalities.?

Tags: laravel, authentication

Output is showing like this.[Output of default authentication functionality of laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0rk0.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using `laravel/ui`. Did you run `npm install` and `npm run dev`?

Comment: I didn't install that.